# Why is Python requests.get() is retrieving outdated data from API?

Tags: python, api, server, get, request

**Context:**

I'm making GET requests to an API, and the API *sometimes* returns data that is up to 5 minutes old. However, when making the same request on Chrome, the data is always up to date. The server is ngnix.
This is the API request made when the page is loaded in Chrome:

```
https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/sell_order?game=csgo&goods_id=781660&_=1604808126524
```

**Relevant Code:**

```
def epochTimestamp():
    return int(round(datetime.now().timestamp()*1000))

def getProxies():
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    return {'http': fr'socks5h://{proxy}', 'https': fr'socks5h://{proxy}'}

get_purchase_headers = {
    'Host': 'buff.163.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
}


url = f"https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/sell_order?game=csgo&goods_id=781660&_={epochTimestamp()}"

source = requests.get(url, timeout=10, proxies=getProxies(), headers=get_purchase_headers)
```

**What I have tried:**

- Including `User-Agent` headers
- `'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'`
- Including timestamp in the URL

Comment: Have you tried `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'`?

Comment: @Ibz tried that too, `"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Pragma": "no-cache"`, but to no avail